# How to set Jenkins pipeline job to always build 'default' branch but only build other branches over night

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Given a Jenkins multibranch pipeline job that uses a property strategy to "suppress automatic SCM triggering" for all branches but 'default', how do you allow Jenkins to wait until night (say 7pm-6am) to build every other branch?

We used to be able to set the Poll SCM strategy for each job individually, which worked well.

Pipeline scripts allow you to set a pollSCM pipeline trigger property. However it won't get set unless the job has run at least once and there seems to be a defect where jobs are continuously triggered by scm changes, making it less useful.

Answer (score 1):

Jenkinsfile properties can (now) configure polling triggers and override the default triggering behaviour. This example enables daily builds for everything except 'default' and release branches (which are always built)

```
def alwaysBuild = (env.BRANCH_NAME == "default" || env.BRANCH_NAME ==~ /release-.*/);
properties([
    overrideIndexTriggers(alwaysBuild), 
    pipelineTriggers([pollSCM('@daily')])
]);
```

NOTE: As of 2016-Sept, there seems to be a bug where pollSCM triggers multiple builds per change. Possibly this bug: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-38443